# Multi threading using async/await and httpclient in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, youtube

I wrote a console application for downloading YouTube preview-images.But I think this program is running synchronously instead async. What did I do wrong and how do I make multi-loading files from web use async/await?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace YoutubePreviewer
{
    class Node
    {
        public string Path { get; private set; }
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public string Source { get; private set; }
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public Previews Previews { get; set; }

        public Node(string p, string t, string s, string i)
        {
            Path = p;
            Title = t;
            Source = s;
            Id = i;
        }

    }

    class Previews
    {
        public string[] Urls { get; private set; }


        public static Previews Get(Node n)
        {
            string[] resolutions = {"default", "hqdefault", "mqdefault", "maxresdefault"};
            for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
            {
                string end = resolutions[i] + ".jpg";
                resolutions[i] = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + n.Id + "/" + resolutions[i] + ".jpg";
            }
            Previews pr = new Previews();
            pr.Urls = resolutions;
            return pr;
        }
    }

    static class Operations
    {
        public static async Task<string> DownloadUrl(string address)
        {
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            return await http.GetStringAsync(address);
        }

        public static async Task<Node> Build(string url)
        {
            var source = await Operations.DownloadUrl(url);
            var title = Regex.Match(source, "<title>(.*)</title>").Groups[1].Value;
            var id = Regex.Match(url, @"watch\?v=(.+)").Groups[1].Value;
            Node node = new Node(url, title, source, id);
            node.Previews =await Task<Previews>.Factory.StartNew(()=>Previews.Get(node);
            return node;
        }

        public static async Task WriteToDisk(Node n, string path = "C:/Downloads")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting downloading {n.Path} previews");
            var securedName = string.Join("_", n.Title.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));

            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, securedName));
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            foreach (var preview in n.Previews.Urls)
            {
                try
                {
                    var arr = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(preview);
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    string name = preview.Substring(preview.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, securedName, name), FileMode.Create,
                        FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        await fs.WriteAsync(arr, 0, arr.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Can't download and save preview  {preview}");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 12));
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"{preview} is saved!");
            }

        }

        public static async Task Load(params string[] urls)
        {

            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                Node n = await Build(url);
                await WriteToDisk(n);

            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static  void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Task t= Operations.Load(File.ReadAllLines("data.txt"));

            Task.WaitAll(t);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You have to create a task for each download. In your code there is only one task which download one file after another.

Comment: if you are trying to download from Youtube then you are violating their ToS

Comment: @uncoder neither of thing you consider wrong is actually wrong... I.e. $ is string interpolation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Your code is downloading URLs and writing them to disk one at a time. It is operating asynchronously, but serially.

If you want it to run asynchronously and *concurrently*, then you should be using something like `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public static async Task LoadAsync(params string[] urls)
{
  var tasks = urls.Select(url => WriteToDisk(Build(url)));
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

(This code assumes that `Build` is a synchronous method, which it should be).

There are also a number of unrelated issues that jump out:

- `node.Previews =await Task<Previews>.Factory.StartNew(()=>Previews.Get(node);` is sending trivial work to the thread pool for no real reason. It should be `node.Previews = Previews.Get(node);`.
- This means that `Operations.Build` doesn't need to be `async`, and indeed it shouldn't be.
- You should be using a single shared instance of `HttpClient` rather than creating a new one for each request.
- `Task.WaitAll(t);` is quite odd. It can be just `t.Wait();`.
- `await Task.Delay(100);` is also unusual.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Stephen Cleary's excellent answer - as he said, this is technically running asynchronously, but that's not actually helping you at all because it's doing things serially - i.e. it *is* asynchronous but the performance is no better than if it actually was just running synchronously.

The key thing to remember here is that async/await will only help you if it actually allows the machine to do more work than it would have done otherwise in a certain amount of time (or if it allows the machine to finish a certain set of tasks faster).

Just to use my favorite analogy: suppose that you're at a restaurant with 9 other people. When the waiter comes by to take orders, the first guy he calls on isn't ready. Clearly, the most efficient thing to do would be to take the order of the other 9 people and then come back to him. Suppose, however, the first guy said, "it's OK to come back to me later, as long as you wait for me to be ready to order first." (This is essentially what you have above - "it's OK to come back to my method to process the download later, as long as you wait for me to finish the download first"). This analogy isn't perfect by any means, but I think that captures the essence of what needs to happen here.

The key thing to remember is that there's only an improvement here if the waiter can accomplish more in the same amount of time or can accomplish a certain set of tasks faster. In this case, he only saves time if he decreases the total amount of time that he spends taking the table's order.

One other thing to remember: it's acceptable to do something like `Task.WaitAll(...)` in a console application (as long as you're not using a synchronization context) but you want to make sure you don't do something like that in a WPF application or something else with a synchronization context as that could cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to control concurrency, so you efficiently utilize the network channel and don't get throttled. So I would suggest to use the [AsyncEnumerator NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator) with such code:

```
using System.Collections.Async;

static class Operations
{
    public static async Task Load(params string[] urls)
    {
        await urls.ParallelForEachAsync(
            async url =>
            {
                Node n = await Build(url);
                await WriteToDisk(n);
            },
            maxDegreeOfParallelism: 10);
    }
}
```